# Refer the attachment Excel Spreadsheet please send me a solution

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

The attached image shows that Cell F52 shows the number 6, which is variable from 1 to 200 and cell N77 shows the value 1663 RS., As the number varies 1 to 200 bill money also changed. I need to make list individuals bill amount in 200 rows and 2 columns.

Example:

```
1 200
2 600
3 ..
4 ..
5 ..
6 1663 
7 ..
etc
```

Please help me macro code for this, I am new to macro.

[image]

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please describe clearly. Thank you

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is extremely vague, but if I understand it correctly then the following would work as long as you add another Sheet in the case below that sheet is called "Result":

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'The sheet where you have to enter your data
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Result") 'The sheet where the results will go
For i = 1 To 200
    ws.Range("F52").Value = i 'change the value of F52 from 1 to 200 in a loop
    ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = i 'write the value in the sheet Result
    ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value = ws.Range("N77") 'get the calculated value from N77
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT HELPS ME LOT